# nginx map module - using regex in included file

Tags: dictionary, module, nginx, url-rewriting, config

I'm using nginx and its map module (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule) to create rewrites depending on $args value.
My config looks like the following:
nginx.conf

```
map $args $myvar {
    default 0;
    include /path/to/file.conf;
}
```

file.conf has something like:

```
foo=1 /url1;
foo=2 /url2;
....
foo=n /urln;
```

afterwards I'm using $myvar for redirects like this

```
location = /somepage.html {
    if ($myvar !~ 0) {
        rewrite ^ $myvar? permanent;
    }
    rewrite ^ /mydefaultpage/? permanent;
}
```

The question is: can I use regex inside my file.conf, which I include inside my `map` directive? So I could write something like

```
~^foo=1(&<suffix>.*)$ /url1?$suffix;
```

and thus preserve all other args when redirecting to /url1.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `/url1?$suffix` in the second argument. It must either be variable or static string.

Try this:

```
map $arg_foo $redirect_to {
    default /mydefaultpage/;
    include /path/to/file.conf;
}

location = /somepage.html {

    set $redirect_args $args;

    if ($args ~ "^(?:(.+)&)?foo=[^&]*(?:&(.+))?$") {
        set $redirect_args $1&$2;
    }

    return 301 $redirect_to?$redirect_args;
}
```